# Unable to enter text using send keys in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to enter text in "keywords" section using send keys command. Please find my below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.antal.com/job-search")

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.ID,'keywords').send_keys("testing")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two elements with same id

I used `driver.find_elements_by_id("keywords")` method to get all of them as a list

and i accessed the required using index number

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.antal.com/job-search")

driver.maximize_window()


elements = driver.find_elements_by_id("keywords") 

ele = elements[1]

ele.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: i tried with above code, but it didn't worked. Basically i want to enter text inside keywords field located under "Add filters to refine results" in the left side of the page.

Comment: @paul I tried and it worked for me, hope you got it

Comment: @Anurag Chandra It will work for now but its not a very good solution as in future if there are more elements introduced with id "keywords", your element index will change. Better way is to always identify element uniquely. ( Last option should be indexing.) Please see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

from selenium import webdriver

def sendText(Element,text):
Element.clear()
Element.send_keys(text)

Element=webdriver.driver.find_element_by_id("enter_your_id_here")
sendText(Element,"Your_data_you_want_to_send")

Comment: Please check the function indentation

Answer (score 0):

Since your locator is not unique for input box where you want to enter text, your code is failing. First try to identify your element uniquely. Please see below link for same:

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium

You can use below xpath to identify your element uniquely.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//form[@name="refineSearchfrm1"]//input[@id="keywords"]').send_keys("testing")
```